# Parse Server Cloud Code Error 141: Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I have just created a parse-server deployment for learning on Cloud9 and everything works fine when I am accessing it using the REST API using PostMan. I am now trying out Cloud Functions.

I have the following code in my cloud.js file,

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Test");
      query.find({
          success: function(data){
              response.success(query);
          },
          error: function(err){
              response.error(err);
          }
      })
});
```

And in the response I get the following error,

```
{
  "code": 141,
  "error": {
    "message": "unauthorized"
  }
}
```

My request on PostMan looks something like this,

[image: Postman request with headers and URL]

The response is fine as long as I do not try a query and send a simple response like `response.success("OK")`.

Is this an issue with Parse or am I missing something related to authorization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was add `useMasterKey: true` in the find method.

```
query.find({ useMasterKey: true, success: function(data){ response.success(query); }, error: function(err){ response.error(err); } })
```